# Coulomb's law: Is $F_1$ equal to $F_2$ even if $q_1$ is not equal to $q_2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, coulombs-law

I am learning the Coulomb's law. So I have question, If $q_2$ be 4 times more than $q_1$, would the force from $q_1$ to $q_2$, still be equal to the force that pushes from $q_2$ to $q_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside: The force **F** on an electric charge $q$ in an electric field **E** is **F** = $ q $ **E**.

For two charges $q_1, q_2$ separated by a distance $r$ you can think of it in two ways:

(1) The first charge creates an electric field E$_1$ = $ q_1 /4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2$ at the second charge and the force experienced by this charge is $ q_2 E_1$.

(2) The second charge creates an electric field E$_2$ = $ q_2 / 4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2$ at the first charge and the force experienced by this charge is $ q_1 E_2$.

(forgetting about vectors for the moment)

In  both cases the result is $$ q_1 q_2 / 4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2 $$

When you take into account the direction of the electric fields you see that the forces are equal in magnitude but in opposite directions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is from Newton's third law, which is experimentally derived. Equal in magnitude, opposite in direction.

Comment: I think you mean _third_ law.